# Show an Image based upon today - date()

Tags: jquery

First off, I know how frustrating it is to repeat questions so please don't think I am doing that as there are plenty of answers on Stackoverflow regarding this. For some reason I can't get them to work. Here is the full JQuery, HTML. (I am doing this on local).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">
    <meta name="dcterms.created" content="Wed, 06 Aug 2014 13:13:03 GMT">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.day-1').css('background-image', function(){

  var url, hour = new Date().getHours();
  if (hour > 7 && hour < 20) {
    return 'images/bg_daytime.png';
   } else {
    return 'images/bg_nighttime.png';
   }
  });
});
</script>

    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

<body>
<div class="DateDiv">
    <img class="day-1" src="img/day-1.jpg" width="250" height="252">
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Now I know logically there is a way this could be smarter, by  replacing the image name instead. My ultimate aim is to have a countdown on the number of days left to a certain date. It would great to replace the image name with this number for example: 25 days left, image name changes to images/day-25.jpg

Although I am looking for the answer, I want to learn to so any logic help for be amazing :)

Yours Sincerly,

JQuery Noob.

----Edited and added code for the JQuery Function--------

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.day-1').parent().css('background-image', function () {
    var hour = new Date().getHours();
    var imagename = new Date().getDate();
    var daysuntil = 30 - imagename;
    var imagefullname = 'images/' + daysuntil + '.jpg'
    var numberofdays = '<h2>' + daysuntil + ' Days Remaining</h2>'

    $('.day-1').attr('src', imagefullname);
    $('.day-text').append(numberofdays);
 });
```

})

Comment: `$('day-1')` should be `$('.day-1')`

Comment: also your script should be added in a [dom ready handler](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: Hi thanks for your comments. I have edited the code to show both of those elements and it is still not working.

Comment: @user3756034 see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/u52bk6qc/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to change the background image behind the "day-1" image. In that case, there are a few things at fault here.

Firstly, you'd need to target the [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) container for the `.day-1` selector.
Secondly, the `background-image` css property should be wrapped in a `url()`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.day-1').parent().css('background-image', function () {
        var hour = new Date().getHours();
        if (hour > 7 && hour < 20) {
            return "url('http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/sunny-day-landscape.jpg')";
        } else {
            return "url('http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2012/178/e/3/a_dark_starry_night_wallpaper_by_s3vendays-d151qon.jpg')";
        }
    });

});
```

If you are simply looking to change the source location of the `day-1` image, you could use the [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method, like this:

```
$('.day-1').attr('src', 'img/day-2.jpg');
```

Comment: Thanks @JamieDunstan, your help enabled me to understand a lot further what I was trying to do. I ended up with:

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.day-1').parent().css('background-image', function () {
        var hour = new Date().getHours();
  var imagename = new Date().getDate();
  var daysuntil = 30 - imagename;
  var imagefullname = 'images/' + daysuntil + '.jpg'
  var numberofdays = '<h2>' + daysuntil + ' Days Remaining</h2>'
        
        $('.day-1').attr('src', imagefullname);
  $('.day-text').append(numberofdays);
     });
})